What does $\mathbb{N}_n$ mean?
Source:
It is written that

Let $H$ be  such that  :
for  every pair  of elements  $i,j \in \mathbb{N}_n$, there  exits $\pi \in H$ such that $\pi(i)=j$. Then $H$ is  called a  transitive  subgroup of $S_n$

Regarding this $\mathbb{N}_n$ notation, I'm a bit confused
My understanding is that $\mathbb{N}$ refers to the natural numbers
What  does $\mathbb{N}_n$ mean?

It is the set of the first $n$ natural numbers. But please note that different places have different conventions, regarding whether $0$ is included, or whether $n$ is included. In simplicial homotopy theory for example, it is more convenient to let $[n]$ be the set $\{0, 1, \dots, n\}$ which contains $(n+1)$ elements.

Aha. So if we call $S_n$ the symmetric group on $n$ letters, then in our case $\mathbb{N}_n$ is the set of these $n$ "letters". So a member $\pi\in S_n$ can be seen as a bijective map $\pi: \mathbb{N}_n\to\mathbb{N}_n$.

I have seen $\overline{1,n}$ for ${1,\dots,n}$ for what it's worth.

In the context of group actions, $S_n$ acts on $X={1,2,\ldots ,n}$ and we have $S_n={\rm Sym}(X)$, the symmetry group. Then it makes sense to assume that $\Bbb N_n=X$. See also this post.
